# Where to enter python scripts?

Tags: python, scripting, command

`python -m cProfile -s time circuit.py < tests/5devadas13.in`

Where do I enter these kinda thing in python? I don't have any IDE. I use idle. I've tried entering it in cmd and idle but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Python is probably not in PATH. Add directory with python(.exe) to your PATH: https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: I've added python to the path. It runs python when i type in python but when i give this command
python -m cProfile -s time circuit.py < tests/5devadas13.in
It says can't find the path specified

Comment: `tests/5devadas13.in` doesnt look like valid path in cmd, which uses `\` as separator.

Comment: found the problem the file wasn't in my current directory.